# Exception raised during haystack unit test

Tags: python, json, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using python 3.5.2, Django 1.9 and django-haystack 2.5.1.

I have some models:

```
class Annotation(TimeStampedModel):
... other attributes ...
    entity = models.ForeignKey('another_app.Entity', blank=True, null=True)

class Entity(models.Model):
... other attributes ...
```

I'm using this configuration in order to override the HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS settings variable with another one (TEST_INDEX) which redirects all tests to a different search index.

```
@override_settings(HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS=TEST_INDEX, HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR='haystack.signals.BaseSignalProcessor')
class SearchEnpointsTests(OurAPITestCase):

    fixtures = ['test_data.json']

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(SearchEnpointsTests, cls).setUpClass()
        haystack.connections.reload('default')
        call_command('update_index', interactive=False, verbosity=0)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        return super(SearchEnpointsTests, cls).tearDownClass()
        # call_command('clear_index', interactive=False, verbosity=0)


test_search(self):
       ...
```

And, as settings variables:

```
# haystack:
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': ELASTICSEARCH_HOST,
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack'
    }
}


TEST_INDEX = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': ELASTICSEARCH_HOST,
        'INDEX_NAME': 'test_index',
    },
}
```

Before configuring haystack real-time, it worked, now that I changed the configuration with this one:

```
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

It raises an exception during testing:

```
File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 160, in __get__
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
AttributeError: 'Annotation' object has no attribute '_entity_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1036, in setUpClass
    'database': db_name,
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 119, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 60, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 100, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 158, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 201, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 745, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 192, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/signals.py", line 52, in handle_save
    index.update_object(instance, using=using)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 278, in update_object
    backend.update(self, [instance])
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 168, in update
    prepped_data = index.full_prepare(obj)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 208, in full_prepare
    self.prepared_data = self.prepare(obj)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 199, in prepare
    self.prepared_data[field.index_fieldname] = field.prepare(obj)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 205, in prepare
    return self.convert(super(CharField, self).prepare(obj))
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 88, in prepare
    values = self.resolve_attributes_lookup(current_objects, attrs)
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/fields.py", line 108, in resolve_attributes_lookup
    if not hasattr(current_object, attributes[0]):
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 169, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get()
  File "/project_folder/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 387, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
apps.another_app.models.DoesNotExist: Problem installing fixture '/project_folder/fixtures/test_data.json': Entity matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Skimming through the haystack code leads me to believe that the haystack related settings matter at module loading time (here: when the test runner starts) as that's when the connections are loaded using those settings. Consider having different settings modules for different environments: e.g. dev, test, staging, production.